# How to make a navigation bar that scrolls with the page past a certain point like this?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How to make the navigation bar like the following where when the user scrolls down, after a certain point, the navigation bar sticks on the left and scrolls as the user scrolls down:

http://developer.android.com/design/get-started/ui-overview.html

Would ideally like to know if there is a simple javascript solution to this, or if jquery is the preferred method. Examples would be appreciated with a div block. I know there is the position: relative; property, but I do not know how one can use it with (javascript?) to make it such that it sticks only after the user scrolls down with the page past a certain point.

Comment: 'Examples would be appreciated.' Really?  Why not show us some examples you've tried.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a lot of digging by inspecting elements. I took a look at the nav and it has an `id` of `devdoc-nav`. If you go into Resources they have a js file called `doc.js` that has this code:

```
  // Set up fixed navbar
  var prevScrollLeft = 0; // used to compare current position to previous position of horiz scroll
  $(window).scroll(function(event) {
    if ($('#side-nav').length == 0) return;
    if (event.target.nodeName == "DIV") {
      // Dump scroll event if the target is a DIV, because that means the event is coming
      // from a scrollable div and so there's no need to make adjustments to our layout
      return;
    }
    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();    
    var headerHeight = $('#header').outerHeight();
    var subheaderHeight = $('#nav-x').outerHeight();
    var searchResultHeight = $('#searchResults').is(":visible") ? 
                             $('#searchResults').outerHeight() : 0;
    var totalHeaderHeight = headerHeight + subheaderHeight + searchResultHeight;
    var navBarShouldBeFixed = scrollTop > totalHeaderHeight;

    var scrollLeft = $(window).scrollLeft();
    // When the sidenav is fixed and user scrolls horizontally, reposition the sidenav to match
    if (navBarIsFixed && (scrollLeft != prevScrollLeft)) {
      updateSideNavPosition();
      prevScrollLeft = scrollLeft;
    }

    // Don't continue if the header is sufficently far away 
    // (to avoid intensive resizing that slows scrolling)
    if (navBarIsFixed && navBarShouldBeFixed) {
      return;
    }

    if (navBarIsFixed != navBarShouldBeFixed) {
      if (navBarShouldBeFixed) {
        // make it fixed
        var width = $('#devdoc-nav').width();
        $('#devdoc-nav')
            .addClass('fixed')
            .css({'width':width+'px'})
            .prependTo('#body-content');
        // add neato "back to top" button
        $('#devdoc-nav a.totop').css({'display':'block','width':$("#nav").innerWidth()+'px'});

        // update the sidenaav position for side scrolling
        updateSideNavPosition();
      } else {
        // make it static again
        $('#devdoc-nav')
            .removeClass('fixed')
            .css({'width':'auto','margin':''})
            .prependTo('#side-nav');
        $('#devdoc-nav a.totop').hide();
      }
      navBarIsFixed = navBarShouldBeFixed;
    } 

    resizeNav(250); // pass true in order to delay the scrollbar re-initialization for performance
  });


  var navBarLeftPos;
  if ($('#devdoc-nav').length) {
    setNavBarLeftPos();
  }
```

You don't necessarily have to understand everything that is going on but the basic idea I want to show you is that all you see **is done through CSS.** The javascript is simply used to apply that CSS at the right times. When the user scrolls past a certain point, the webpage applies a class called `fixed` (you can find this in the `default.css`)

```
  #devdoc-nav.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  margin:0;
  top: 20px; }
```

So yeah hopefully from here you can get an idea. There are many ways to go about doing this but since you showed this example, I am simply showing you the code they have and maybe you can draw something from it. If you need help, don't hesitate to comment.

Comment: Does that mean my example provided, Google actually used Jquery?

Comment: Yes it does. If you look in the Resources under the file `global-libraries-combined.js` they have a bunch of libraries smashed into one js file including jquery, jqueryui, prettify, jScrollPane, etc

Answer (score 0):

Twitter Bootstrap has an 'affix' component that will do this for you - http://rc.getbootstrap.com/javascript.html#affix

If you want to write something similar yourself you need to:

- Set the element as "position:absolute" (this is usually OK if you set the parent element to "position:relative").
- Make an onscroll event handler, and in it check how far from the top or bottom of the viewport your element is.
- Set the position as "fixed" when you want it to stay visible (e.g. once the user has scrolled down 100px), and back to absolute when you don't.

Answer (score 0):

Anthony Garand's [`sticky.js`](http://labs.anthonygarand.com/sticky) jquery plugin has worked quite well for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery window.scrollTop() to do this if you don't want additional plugins.